# A Bertini-type result for hypersurfaces containing a subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $P$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $4$ and let $Z$ be an irreducible subvariety  of dimension $2$ ($Z$ is not necessarily smooth, but you can assume it).

> Is there a smooth, irreducible *ample* hypersurface $H \subseteq P$ such that $H$ contains $Z$?

I first tried to mimic Hartshorne's argument for Bertini theorem, but I could only prove the case when $Z$ is smooth of dimension $\leq 1$.

Then I tried to blowup $Z$ and take a general hypersurface on $\textrm{Bl}_Z(X)$. But I don't know how to control the regularity and ampleness for the pushforward of this hypersurface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For non-smooth $Z$ the answer is in general **no**.

Take $P=\mathbb{P}^4$ and let $Z \subset \mathbb P^4$ be a surface with a non-normal double point $p$ (i.e. a singularity locally analytically isomorphic to the one given by two planes intersecting in a single point, it is no difficult to construct irreducible examples, for instance taking general projections from smooth surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^5$).

Then there is no smooth hypersurface $H$ containing $Z$, since the singularity $p$ has embedding dimension $4$.

---

**Added.** Here is another counterexample, showing that the answer is in general **no** even if $Z$ smooth.

Let $P=\mathbb{P}^4$ and $Z \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ be a smooth surface which is not a complete intersection (for instance, an abelian surface). If $H$ is any hypersurface containing $X$, by the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem the induced restriction map between Picard groups $$\textrm{Pic} \, \mathbb{P}^4 \longrightarrow \  \textrm{Pic} \, H$$ is an isomorphism. Then, if $X$ were a Cartier divisor in $H$, it would be a complete intersection there, hence a complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^4$, contradiction.

This shows that $Z$ is not a Cartier divisor inside $H$, hence $H$ is necessarily singular at some point of $Z$.

Comment: Even for smooth $Z$, the answer is still no.  Let $S$ be a K3 surface that contains a smooth rational curve $C$.  Let $P$, resp. $Z$, be the Hilbert scheme parameterizing $0$-dimensional, length $2$ closed subschemes of $S$, resp. of $C$.  By Fujiki / Beauville, $P$ is a hyperKaehler manifold.  Of course $Z$ is $\mathbb{P}^2$.  The normal bundle of $Z$ in $P$ is $\Omega_Z$.  Since this is not an extension of two invertible sheaves (as I have explained here before -- use Whitney sum), there is no divisor in $P$ containing $Z$ that is smooth at every point of $Z$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: another counterexample in the smooth case is provided by a surface $Z \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ which is not a complete intersection. I added this in the answer.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I rethink about your second example, and found the following thing which I cannot explain: Suppose we blowup $Z$ and obtain a new variety $\tilde P$. Choose a general ample divisor $\tilde H$ in $\tilde P$, it will cut the exceptional divisor horizontally, hence its image $H$ in $P$ should contain $Z$. Then you find a Cartier divisor containing $Z$. The problem I guess may come from $Z$ is  a complete intersection in $H$ may not imply it is a c.i. in $P$.

Comment: Also, if the above argument works (i.e. blowup, intersect then pushforward), then any subvariety will be contained as a hypersurface of some ambient variety (but the ambient variety may not smooth as your first example showed).

Comment: @LiYutong: I do not completely follow your first comment. Of course there exist Cartier divisors in $P$ containing $Z$, every divisor $H \subset P$ is Cartier, since $P$ is smooth. The point is that *$Z$ is not Cartier inside $H$*, hence $H$ is necessarily a singular (Cartier) divisor in $P$.   

This means that for any choice of your "horizontal" divisor $\tilde H \subset \tilde P$, the pushforward $H:=\pi_* \tilde H$ inside $P$ will never be smooth.

Comment: Dear @FrancescoPolizzi I apologize that I did not understand your example in the first comment and keep asking: in your construction, if $Z$ were a Cartier divisor in $H$, then it is a locally complete intersection in $X$(I guess you meant $locally$, right?) By Lefschetz, there is a Cartier divisor $L$ on $P$, such that $\mathcal{O}_X(L|_X) = \mathcal{O}_X(Z)$, but this does not mean that as $Cartier$ divisors, we have $L|_X = Z$. Why does this contradict the non (locally) complete intersection of $Z$?

Comment: @LiYutong: let's try again. By Lefschetz theorem, if $Z$ were Cartier in $H$, it would be a hypersurface section here (since $\textrm{Pic}(H)$ is generated by the hyperplane section). On the other hand, $H$ is a hypersurface in $P=\mathbb{P}^4$, hence $Z$ would be  a *global* complete intersection in $P$, being a hypersurface section of a hypersurface.
 On the other hand, by assumption,  my surface $Z$ is *not* a global complete intersection in $P$, so the argument above shows that  $Z$ is a Weil divisor but *not* a Cartier divisor in $H$. Then $H$ is singular along some point of $Z$.

Comment: Thank you for your patient!!! I believe I understand it now: any Cartier divisor on $X$ can be extends to a Cartier divisor on $P$ (or any meromorphic function on $X$ can be extends to a meromorphic function on $P$).

Comment: Your $X$ is $H$? If so, yes. This is precisely the meaning of the fact that by Lefchetz theorem the restriction map $$\textrm{Pic}\,P \to \textrm{Pic}\,H$$ is surjective.